# HTML/CSS: Inner, bottom bound div going over the top when the screen height gets small

Tags: html, css, dynamic

The goal:
I'm trying to make a full screen div that will dynamically adjust itself to all screen heights (example: http://full-vert.webflow.com/).

Problem:
I'm having a struggle with the child div going over the top of it's parent div, when it's bound to bottom and the screen height is being adjusted. Is there a way to make this child div to stop scaling with the height of the page? 

HTML

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="bottom">

        <h1>Hi!</h1>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>

    </div>

</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    background-color: #f9f9f9;
    width: 100%;
    height:150px;
    position: relative;
}

.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}
```

Here is a jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Lboyrqnc/ 
Try different values on .container { height: 200px;}. Eg. 50px to 150px and you'll see my point.
ps. I'm using height: 100vh though. 
Edit:
To really show what I mean try this: put the .container height to 100vh (which is 100% of current browser window height) then make the browser windowed mode and drag the window's bottom up and down and you'll see how the h1 will go over (under in this case) it's parent div.

Comment: you want your bottom always to be fixed?? irrespective of your content in container

Comment: Yes, I want the .bottom to be fixed to the .container bottom, because that's how the content (h1,p) will be dynamic to the height of the .container. If I would bound the .bottom to eg. .container's top part, there would be a huge gap between the content (h1,p) and the bottom of the container.

Answer (score 0):

What if you add

```
top: 0;
```

to the .bottom class?

Comment: Nope, that only overrides the .container height property and makes the .bottom to be static, which I don't want.

Answer (score 0):

Add max-height to

```
.bottom {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-height:200px;
}
```

it works

fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/harshdand/h84jfn3o/

Comment: or make `position:relative` for class .bottom